# Why ParNew GC time rise with old generation size?

Tags: java, garbage-collection

I found a stranger thing, ParNew GC time risen with old generation size, and after Old GC(CMS), it's back to normal again. **Is old generation size effect young gc time?**

[Grafana GC Metrics](https://i.stack.imgur.com/flCcM.png)

[Young GC log between Major GC](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GCPn2.png)

Here's my jvm options:

```
-server -Xmx6656M -Xms6656M -Xmn4436M -XX:SurvivorRatio=8 -XX:MetaspaceSize=256m -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=512m 

-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:ParallelGCThreads=4 -XX:ConcGCThreads=3 -XX:MaxTenuringThreshold=7 -XX:+CMSParallelInitialMarkEnabled -XX:+ParallelRefProcEnabled -XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=75 -XX:+UseCMSInitiatingOccupancyOnly 

-Xloggc:/dev/shm/gc.log -XX:+PrintGCDetails -XX:+PrintGCDateStamps -XX:+PrintTenuringDistribution -XX:+UseGCLogFileRotation -XX:NumberOfGCLogFiles=2 -XX:GCLogFileSize=50M 

-XX:-UseCounterDecay -XX:AutoBoxCacheMax=20000 -XX:+AlwaysPreTouch -XX:MaxJavaStackTraceDepth=10000 -XX:-OmitStackTraceInFastThrow -XX:+UseCountedLoopSafepoints -XX:-UseBiasedLocking -XX:+ExplicitGCInvokesConcurrent -XX:+ExplicitGCInvokesConcurrentAndUnloadsClasses
```

I suspect it's because of something like memory compact when young gc working.

How can I fix this?

Comment: When scavenge is done, the gc needs to trace ref:s from old gen into new gen to find if the new gen object is still live. If there are more objects in old gen that will obviously take more time. Are you stuck on java 8? Otherwise, try to upgrade to G1.

Answer (score 0):

Young GC with CMS collector involves dirty card scanning to capture old-to-young references. Size of dirty card table is proportional to size of old space.

More details are available in [this article](https://blog.ragozin.info/2011/06/understanding-gc-pauses-in-jvm-hotspots.html).

Comment: That makes sense, but not completely. I have not see this happed in other application. They are using the same GC policy, but this app young generation's size bigger.

And now the ratio of young to old is  2:1, Should I turn down young generation's size to resolve this?

Comment: 130ms pause is probably to big for CMS with 6.5G heap. Though tuning requires more input. I had a checklist for CMS tuning, it is outdated tough https://blog.ragozin.info/2011/07/gc-check-list-for-data-grid-nodes.html

Comment: I've noticed time spent in "scrub string table" phase. You may be abusing String.intern()